# I want to write a chordal rhythmn guitar part to my melodic rhythmn part of my song but i cant figure out how

Tags: guitar

I have written a melodic lead part to my J-Rock-style song in single notes. I just had the melody and wrote around it. Now to want a rocky rhythm part but I cant figure that out. How can I compose the track? I know the notes in the melody but that doesn't help because I am quite the theory beginner. Help would be great.

Regards Leon;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find chords to go with my melody in music I write](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29511/how-do-i-find-chords-to-go-with-my-melody-in-music-i-write)

Comment: @Aaron - I don't think that's a duplicate - I think the OP has more trouble writing the *rhythm* of the rhythm part than the *harmony* like your linked question suggests.

Comment: The question could even mean, "what sort of logic do people use when they add other notes besides a melody." In which case an answer would need to explain that there's this thing called _chords_... And that some people might even just add a bass note here and there without knowing about chords.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, think of your **melody notes** as **chord tones**. Not a group of them at once, but each individually.

For example, if the note is a **G**, then the chord should have that G. It doesn't need to be G major or minor; it could be C major (C E G) or minor (C Eb G). Maybe E minor (E G B).

And not every note needs to fit, as long as they're not too jarring. If there's a G and a B, go G major instead of G minor.

There could be a temptation to go fully **diatonic**: all the notes on the melody are in the C major scale, all the chords are C, Dmin, Emin, F, G, Amin. This is appropriate for country or folk, for example, but in jazz, you are encouraged to vary wildly from this. I don't know the stylistic standards for J-rock (I have passing familiarity with Shonan Knife and the Boredoms, but figure that's a generation away from your desired sound).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out common rhythmic accompaniment patterns in J-rock, especially those that accompany melody passages with rhythms like yours. ...Oh, you can't find any melody passages in existing J-rock with rhythms like yours? *Then I doubt you just composed J-rock.*

Then, whatever the chord progression for your melody is, use those common rhythmic accompaniment patterns in the rhythm part that you're composing.

For example, if you find that an 8th note-16th note-16th note pattern is common in J-rock accompaniments, use that.